# Unloading an swf upon exiting frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've had a search around and couldn't apply anything i found to my code to get it to work.

I'm building a site where navigating to each page (frame) will load an external swf with the content. ideally i would like for the content to unload when i navigate away from the frame, so that i can then load a new swf.
here's my as3 for loading the swf:

> var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();
>
> stage.addChild(swfLoader); swfLoader.x = 0; swfLoader.y = 100;
>
> var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("gallery_swf/reg_slide.swf");
>
> swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
>   loadProdComplete);
>
> swfLoader.load(bgURL);
>
> function loadProdComplete(e:Event):void {
>
> trace("file loaded");
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
swfLoader.unload();
```

to unload the swf.

Comment: In the event handler which navigate away from the frame.

Comment: ok, so that's worked in unloading the swf when navigating away from the frame, but unfortunately presents another issue. when i navigate back to that frame, the swf doesn't re-load, like i need it to. it seems the unloader negates the action script asking it to loadthe swf?

Comment: This might be useful for you: http://www.beautifycode.com/the-finer-art-of-loading-1-simple-load-unload

Answer (score 0):

The safest method to unload an external swf is to use the [unloadAndStop](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-player-10-action-script.html) method of your loader. If you are targeting Flash Player 9 tho, you will not be able to use this method and will have to use `unload()` instead. Please note that `unload()` requires additional manual work to ensure everything is properly unloaded.

To quote the link :

> Though Loader.unload removes the child of the Loader object, the unloaded object will still run in the background until it is actually disposed of by the garbage collector. Since the garbage collector does not dispose of objects that are referred to, the "unloaded" content could perhaps never be removed (for example, event listeners could reference the object).

Comment: thanks, that's worked but encountered the same issue as explained below - "ok, so that's worked in unloading the swf when navigating away from the frame, but unfortunately presents another issue. when i navigate back to that frame, the swf doesn't re-load, like i need it to. it seems the unloader negates the action script asking it to loadthe swf?"